# Table already exists after rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran `rake db:migrate` and I'm getting the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'sdk_wizard_sessions' already exists: CREATE TABLE `sdk_wizard_sessions` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `using_mediation` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `selected_networks` text NOT NULL, `selected_games` text NOT NULL, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
```

I've looked on stackoverflow and it seems like no one has a good solution for this. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The table already exists....  Either drop the table

```
rails g migration DropSdkWizardSession
```

and enter the following code in the created migration

```
class DropSdkWizardSession < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :sdk_wizard_sessions
  end
end
```

or you could alter the current table so that it looks like the table you were trying to create (I think the better of the three options)

```
rails g migration ChangeSdkWizardSession
```

and add this code to the created migration

```
class ChangeSdkWizardSession < ActiveRecord::Migration
  change_table :sdk_wizard_sessions do |t|
    t.remove :description, :name  #this will remove columns named :description or :name
    t.string :part_number         #this will add column of type string, called :part_number
    t.index :part_number          #this will add an index for column :part_number
    t.rename :upccode, :upc_code  #this would rename column :upccode, to :upc_code
  end
end
```

or you could create an new table and name it something different (lazy option)